# How to set indexOn rule on firebase with auth.uid variable?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to set a rule on a node in firebaseDatabase, but I get error

> Error saving rules - Line 85: Key names can't contain ".", "#", "$",
>   "/", "[", or "]" (unbound names start with "$")

As I understand `auth.uid` is a global variable for the current logged in user. How can I fix this?

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null", 

        "notifications/auth.uid": {
        ".indexOn":["createdAt"]    
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to store notifications for each user under their `auth.uid` and allow querying those by defining an index, then you're looking for these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null", 

    "notifications": {
      "$uid": {
        ".indexOn":["createdAt"]    
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `$uid` here is a wildcard, and applies to each node under `notifications`. To learn more about this, see [Using $ Variables to Capture Path Segments](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#using_variables_to_capture_path_segments).

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue

```
"notifications/auth.uid"
```

as it's treating everything inside the quotes as a string so the period is causing the error and paths cannot include a period character. Also, it will not resolve the auth.uid as it's just a string, not the variable you want. You could do something like

```
root.child('notifications').child(auth.uid) {...
```

or even

```
root.child( 'notifications/' + auth.uid ) {...
```